# Meaning of "She wheedled her mother into buying John a mink coat"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does "She wheedled her mother into buying John a mink coat" mean?

Does it mean "She wheedled her mother and her mother bought a mink coat and her mother gave John a mink coat" or "She wheedled her mother and her mother bought a mink coat from John"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: The sentence was originally `She wheedled her mother into buying her a mink coat.`*

---

This question would likely be better suited for English Learners Stack Exchange. That being said, I will go ahead and answer it since I know the answer.

The line means that the daughter convinced (through implied coaxing) her mother to buy her (the daughter) a mink coat. The mother did not buy the coat for herself.

You can tell this is the intent of the line because `she` is the subject, while `mother` is merely the object. The focus is still on `she`, so any pronoun will refer back to it rather than `mother`. If `mother` was used as a subject, then the `her` would refer to the mother instead.

---

Consider the result of replacing `her` with a name. I'll use a masculine name for emphasis.

> She wheedled her mother into buying John a mink coat.

In this example, it is obvious that the coat is for John.

Comment: Yes. i move the question to  English Learners Stack Exchange